# I want to change the contains text of the element on run time - By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'ProductName')]");

Tags: java, selenium, automation, findelement

I have multiple products on the Screen, each of them differs from the string "ProductName". Instead of collecting all the products onto the page. I want to make any dynamic or reusable function so that I can pass the product name on the function and it should recognize the element

```
public findElement(String ProductName)
{
     element= By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'ProductName')]");
}
```

If I pass the product name to Apple, then it should give me the locator as

```
element= By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'apple')]");
```

Comment: Did my answer resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like following:

```
public findElement(List<String> products)
{
   for(String product : products){
       String xpath = String.format("//a[contains(text(),'%s')]",product);
       element= By.xpath(xpath);
   }

}
```